# How to access the results of queries?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I am working on writing a simple test to validate that the number of distinct values in an "id" column matches the number of rows for each table. I am expecting to be able to access particular values of an object, but when I run code and try to print the value of my variable, I can see that my object is a sqlalchemy.engine.result.ResultProxy object at..., as opposed to being something human readable. I have been on the SQLAlchemy website for over an hour, and have googled several permutations of my question, but have not found what I am looking for.

My code, with terminal output, is below:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine 
engine = create_engine('postgresql://kyle.pekosh@localhost:5432/testload')
connection = engine.connect()
id_count = connection.execute('SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(id)) FROM csv.agencies')
id_count
<sqlalchemy.engine.result.ResultProxy object at 0x10357d290>
```

Comment: Please open up the repl/import sqlachemy and run ***help(sqlalchemy.engine.result.ResultProxy)*** There are lots of explanation on the ResultProxy results there.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

This is SQLAlchemy's expected behavior. You need to interact with the ResultProxy. As per SQLAlchemy's [documentation](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_1_1/core/connections.html):

> The returned result is an instance of ResultProxy, which references a DBAPI cursor and provides a largely compatible interface with that of the DBAPI cursor. The DBAPI cursor will be closed by the ResultProxy when all of its result rows (if any) are exhausted. A ResultProxy that returns no rows, such as that of an UPDATE statement (without any returned rows), releases cursor resources immediately upon construction.

The ResultProxy [API](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_1_1/core/connections.html#sqlalchemy.engine.ResultProxy) allows you to fetch the data:

```
results = connection.execute('SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(id)) FROM csv.agencies')
id_count = results.first()[0]
```