# Print Results of Queries Python

Tags: python, sql, database, flask, sqlalchemy

My application uses SQLAlchemy/SQL to query a database. I want to print out the result of the query, but I am getting a `<sqlalchemy.engine.result.ResultProxy object` in response.

I tried out the suggestions in [How to access the results of queries?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46370123/how-to-access-the-results-of-queries) but I am getting an `"Uncaught exception"`

See code below:

```
query = f"SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT id)"\
    f"FROM group"

result = db.session.execute(query)
id_count = result.first()[0]
print(id_count)
```

Comment: I'm not 100% sure, but try to iterate over `id_count`

Comment: @RomanBanakh when I iterate over and print, I get `completed` printed out one letter at a time. I am assuming this is the status of my query, but is there a way to print/log the data of the actual query?

Comment: I think you may find an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17972020/how-to-execute-raw-sql-in-flask-sqlalchemy-app)

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
query = f"SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT id)"\
    f"FROM group"

result = db.session.execute(query)
id_count = result.first()

for i in id_count:
    print(i[0]) # Access by positional index
    print(i['my_column']) # Access by column name as a string
    r_dict = dict(i.items()) # convert to dict keyed by column names
```